# How to fill some column with constant string followed by variable number

Tags: sql, string, oracle, plsql

I need to fill a table column (in Oracle database) with string values that have variable part, e. g. AB0001, AB0002,...,AB0112...,AB9999, where AB is constant string part, 0001 -9999 is variable number part. i've tried the following solution in SQL for a table with 2 columns:

```
    create table tbl1
    (seq1 number(8),
     string1 varchar(32));
```

```
    declare
    tst number(8) :=0;
    begin
      for cntr in 1..100
      loop
        tst := cntr;
        insert into TBL1 values (someseq.nextval, concat('AB',tst));
      end loop;
    end;
```

But in this case I get STRING1 filled with values AB1,AB2,...,AB10,.. which is not exactly what I need.
How should I modify my script to insert values like AB0001,...,AB0010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either pad the number with zeros, or format it with leading zeros:

```
insert into TBL1
values (someseq.nextval, concat('AB', to_char(tst, 'FM0000'));
```

The 'FM' format modifier prevents a space being added (to allow for a minus sign).

For your specific example you don't need a PL/SQL block; you could use a [hierarchical query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/queries003.htm) to generate the data for the rows:

```
insert into tbl1(seq1, string1)
select someseq.nextval, concat('AB', to_char(level, 'FM0000'))
from dual
connect by level <= 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

use the lpad function

```
select lpad(1, 4, '0') from dual
--> '0001'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
INSER INTO table_name(code)
VALUES(CONCAT('AB', LPAD('99', 4, '0'));
```

or You can Update on the basis of PK after insertion

```
UPDATE table_name SET code = CONCAT('AB', LPAD(PK_Column_Name, 4, '0') ;
```

or You Can Use Triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgI_Terms_UpdateTermOrder
ON DB.table_name 
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE  t
    SET     code = CONCAT('AB', LPAD(Id, 4, '0') 
    FROM    DB.table_name t INNER JOIN inserted i ON t.Id = I.Id
END;
GO
```